# Google Finance error: invalid literal

Tags: python, google-finance, stockquotes

I was trying to work on a person project (stock market predictions) for school, when Google started acting up again...

I realize that Google Finance has been complete garbage this past year, but it still seemed to be working somewhat up until this morning.
I got an error the first time I ran the code even though it worked fine yesterday.

So I tried just running a sample code from the actual library page: https://pypi.org/project/googlefinance.client/

```
!pip install googlefinance.client

from googlefinance.client import get_price_data, get_prices_data, get_prices_time_data

# Dow Jones
param = {
    'q': ".DJI", # Stock symbol (ex: "AAPL")
    'i': "86400", # Interval size in seconds ("86400" = 1 day intervals)
    'x': "INDEXDJX", # Stock exchange symbol on which stock is traded (ex: "NASD")
    'p': "1Y" # Period (Ex: "1Y" = 1 year)
}
# get price data (return pandas dataframe)
df = get_price_data(param)
print(df)

params = [
    # Dow Jones
    {
        'q': ".DJI",
        'x': "INDEXDJX",
    },
    # NYSE COMPOSITE (DJ)
    {
        'q': "NYA",
        'x': "INDEXNYSEGIS",
    },
    # S&P 500
    {
        'q': ".INX",
        'x': "INDEXSP",
    }
]
period = "1Y"
# get open, high, low, close, volume data (return pandas dataframe)
df = get_prices_data(params, period)
print(df)
```

and still got

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-df3429694fd0> in <module>()
      9 }
     10 # get price data (return pandas dataframe)
---> 11 df = get_price_data(param)
     12 print(df)
     13 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/googlefinance/client.py in get_price_data(query)
     13                 cols = price.split(",")
     14                 if cols[0][0] == 'a':
---> 15                         basetime = int(cols[0][1:])
     16                         index.append(datetime.fromtimestamp(basetime))
     17                         data.append([float(cols[4]), float(cols[2]), float(cols[3]), float(cols[1]), int(cols[5])])

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'nd&nbsp;...</span><br></div></div><div class="g"><h3 class="r"><a href="/url?q=https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DJI_(company)&amp;sa=U&amp;ved=0ahUKEwiB-e_gjMzcAhUpwlkKHTTUC74QFghGMAw&amp;usg=AOvVaw1ugw
```

has anyone run into this before and know what's wrong or how to fix it?

Or, on a separate note, does anyone know of a good alternative to Google Finance?

Comment: Try the yahoo finance library

Comment: Uhm.. well `nd&nbsp;...</span><br></div></div><div class="g"><h3 class="r"><a href="/url?q=https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DJI_(company)&amp;sa=U&amp;ved=0ahUKEwiB-e_gjMzcAhUpwlkKHTTUC74QFghGMAw&amp;usg=AOvVaw1ugw` definitely isn't an integer. It seems to me like you're parsing the data incorrectly. Could you post the raw data you get back from Google?

Comment: @NoahM. Where do I find that? I just copy pasted the code from google.finance library page and this is what it spat out instead of what it says on its page it should have.

Comment: @ᴡʜᴀᴄᴋᴀᴍᴀᴅᴏᴏᴅʟᴇ3000 yahoo finance also doesn't work .... `YQLResponseMalformedError: Response malformed.`

Comment: @ᴡʜᴀᴄᴋᴀᴍᴀᴅᴏᴏᴅʟᴇ3000 tho `fix-yahoo-finance` seems to work ok

Comment: Looks like Google closed the API. The finance.google.com/finance/getprices URL just redirects to a normal Google search now.

Answer (score 1):

It was a problem with the example code. If you go to the [GitHub Homepage](https://github.com/pdevty/googlefinance-client-python), you'll get the latest version—even the small updates.

I slightly modified `client.py` and had no problems with the output.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding: utf-8
import requests
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd


def get_price_data(query):
    r = requests.get(
        "https://finance.google.com/finance/getprices", params=query)
    lines = r.text.splitlines()
    data = []
    index = []
    basetime = 0
    for price in lines:
        cols = price.split(",")
        if cols[0][0] == 'a':
            basetime = int(cols[0][1:])
            index.append(datetime.fromtimestamp(basetime))
            data.append([float(cols[4]), float(cols[2]), float(
                cols[3]), float(cols[1]), int(cols[5])])
        elif cols[0][0].isdigit():
            date = basetime + (int(cols[0]) * int(query['i']))
            index.append(datetime.fromtimestamp(date))
            data.append([float(cols[4]), float(cols[2]), float(
                cols[3]), float(cols[1]), int(cols[5])])
    return pd.DataFrame(data, index=index, columns=['Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Volume'])


def get_closing_data(queries, period):
    closing_data = []
    for query in queries:
        query['i'] = 86400
        query['p'] = period
        r = requests.get(
            "https://finance.google.com/finance/getprices", params=query)
        lines = r.text.splitlines()
        data = []
        index = []
        basetime = 0
        for price in lines:
            cols = price.split(",")
            if cols[0][0] == 'a':
                basetime = int(cols[0][1:])
                date = basetime
                data.append(float(cols[1]))
                index.append(datetime.fromtimestamp(date).date())
            elif cols[0][0].isdigit():
                date = basetime + (int(cols[0]) * int(query['i']))
                data.append(float(cols[1]))
                index.append(datetime.fromtimestamp(date).date())
        s = pd.Series(data, index=index, name=query['q'])
        closing_data.append(s[~s.index.duplicated(keep='last')])
    return pd.concat(closing_data, axis=1)


def get_open_close_data(queries, period):
    open_close_data = pd.DataFrame()
    for query in queries:
        query['i'] = 86400
        query['p'] = period
        r = requests.get(
            "https://finance.google.com/finance/getprices", params=query)
        lines = r.text.splitlines()
        data = []
        index = []
        basetime = 0
        for price in lines:
            cols = price.split(",")
            if cols[0][0] == 'a':
                basetime = int(cols[0][1:])
                date = basetime
                data.append([float(cols[4]), float(cols[1])])
                index.append(datetime.fromtimestamp(date).date())
            elif cols[0][0].isdigit():
                date = basetime + (int(cols[0]) * int(query['i']))
                data.append([float(cols[4]), float(cols[1])])
                index.append(datetime.fromtimestamp(date).date())
        df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=index, columns=[
                          query['q'] + '_Open', query['q'] + '_Close'])
        open_close_data = pd.concat(
            [open_close_data, df[~df.index.duplicated(keep='last')]], axis=1)
    return open_close_data


def get_prices_data(queries, period):
    prices_data = pd.DataFrame()
    for query in queries:
        query['i'] = 86400
        query['p'] = period
        r = requests.get(
            "https://finance.google.com/finance/getprices", params=query)
        lines = r.text.splitlines()
        data = []
        index = []
        basetime = 0
        for price in lines:
            cols = price.split(",")
            if cols[0][0] == 'a':
                basetime = int(cols[0][1:])
                date = basetime
                data.append([float(cols[4]), float(cols[2]), float(
                    cols[3]), float(cols[1]), int(cols[5])])
                index.append(datetime.fromtimestamp(date).date())
            elif cols[0][0].isdigit():
                date = basetime + (int(cols[0]) * int(query['i']))
                data.append([float(cols[4]), float(cols[2]), float(
                    cols[3]), float(cols[1]), int(cols[5])])
                index.append(datetime.fromtimestamp(date).date())
        df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=index, columns=[
                          query['q'] + '_Open', query['q'] + '_High', query['q'] + '_Low', query['q'] + '_Close', query['q'] + '_Volume'])
        prices_data = pd.concat(
            [prices_data, df[~df.index.duplicated(keep='last')]], axis=1)
    return prices_data


def get_prices_time_data(queries, period, interval):
    prices_time_data = pd.DataFrame()
    for query in queries:
        query['i'] = interval
        query['p'] = period
        r = requests.get(
            "https://finance.google.com/finance/getprices", params=query)
        lines = r.text.splitlines()
        data = []
        index = []
        basetime = 0
        for price in lines:
            cols = price.split(",")
            if cols[0][0] == 'a':
                basetime = int(cols[0][1:])
                date = basetime
                data.append([float(cols[4]), float(cols[2]), float(
                    cols[3]), float(cols[1]), int(cols[5])])
                index.append(datetime.fromtimestamp(date))
            elif cols[0][0].isdigit():
                date = basetime + (int(cols[0]) * int(query['i']))
                data.append([float(cols[4]), float(cols[2]), float(
                    cols[3]), float(cols[1]), int(cols[5])])
                index.append(datetime.fromtimestamp(date))
        df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=index, columns=[
                          query['q'] + '_Open', query['q'] + '_High', query['q'] + '_Low', query['q'] + '_Close', query['q'] + '_Volume'])
        prices_time_data = pd.concat(
            [prices_time_data, df[~df.index.duplicated(keep='last')]], axis=1)
    return prices_time_data
```

***Snippet***

```
params = {
    'q': ".DJI",  # Stock symbol (ex: "AAPL")
    'i': "86400",  # Interval size in seconds ("86400" = 1 day intervals)
    # Stock exchange symbol on which stock is traded (ex: "NASD")
    'x': "INDEXDJX",
    'p': "1Y"  # Period (Ex: "1Y" = 1 year)
}
df = get_price_data(params)
print(df)
```

***Output***

> Volume                         Open      High        ...      Close
>   328405532 2017-08-01 15:00:00  21961.42  21990.96    ...      21963.92
>   328405532 2017-08-02 15:00:00  22004.36  22036.10    ...      22016.24
>   336824836 2017-08-03 15:00:00  22007.58  22044.85    ...      22026.10
>   278731064 2017-08-04 15:00:00  22058.39  22092.81    ...      22092.81
>   253635270 2017-08-07 15:00:00  22100.20  22121.15    ...      22118.42
>   213012378 2017-08-08 15:00:00  22095.14  22179.11    ...      22085.34

Comment: Sorry for not following up. Did you figure it out? If not, I'm sure there's another solution.

Comment: No, I switched to Yahoo finance :\ ... They both work sporadically, but Yahoo seems a bit more consistent.

Answer (score 0):

For the last 48 hours or so `".INX"` has not been updating on my google sheets. `.DJI` and `.IXIC` are still updating, although I think one of them wasn't for a while recently.

Answer (score 0):

When scraping Google Finance, it is not necessary really to use any API unless you really want to.  It will be enough to use the `BeautifulSoup` web scraping library, with its help you can scrape all the information you need, and pretty much everything from the ticker page.

[Check code in online IDE](https://replit.com/@denisskopa/stackoverflow-scrape-google-finance-stock-price-bs4#main.py).

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests, lxml, json
from itertools import zip_longest


def scrape_google_finance(ticker: str):
    # https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#passing-parameters-in-urls
    params = {
        "hl": "en" # language
        }

    # https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#custom-headers
    # https://www.whatismybrowser.com/detect/what-is-my-user-agent
    headers = {
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/100.0.4896.60 Safari/537.36",
        }

    html = requests.get(f"https://www.google.com/finance/quote/{ticker}", params=params, headers=headers, timeout=30)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, "lxml")
    
    ticker_data = {"right_panel_data": {},
                    "ticker_info": {}}
    
    ticker_data["ticker_info"]["title"] = soup.select_one(".zzDege").text
    ticker_data["ticker_info"]["current_price"] = soup.select_one(".AHmHk .fxKbKc").text
    
    right_panel_keys = soup.select(".gyFHrc .mfs7Fc")
    right_panel_values = soup.select(".gyFHrc .P6K39c")
    
    for key, value in zip_longest(right_panel_keys, right_panel_values):
        key_value = key.text.lower().replace(" ", "_")

        ticker_data["right_panel_data"][key_value] = value.text
    
    return ticker_data
    

data = scrape_google_finance(ticker="GOOGL:NASDAQ")

print(json.dumps(data, indent=2))
```

Example output

```
{
  "right_panel_data": {
    "previous_close": "$118.84",
    "day_range": "$119.46 - $120.56",
    "year_range": "$101.88 - $151.55",
    "market_cap": "1.57T USD",
    "avg_volume": "34.44M",
    "p/e_ratio": "22.76",
    "dividend_yield": "-",
    "primary_exchange": "NASDAQ",
    "ceo": "Sundar Pichai",
    "founded": "Oct 2, 2015",
    "headquarters": "Mountain View, CaliforniaUnited States",
    "website": "abc.xyz",
    "employees": "174,014"
  },
  "ticker_info": {
    "title": "Alphabet Inc Class A",
    "current_price": "$120.11"
  }
}
```

---

There's a [scrape Google Finance Ticker Quote Data in Python](https://serpapi.com/blog/scrape-google-finance-ticker-quote-data-in-python/) blog post if you need to scrape more data from Google Finance.